# One-to-one functions on a closed interval

Tags: calculus, continuity

From 1973 AP Calculus BC: Section I [page 184 for answer (and 38 for the question)](https://crunchymath.weebly.com/uploads/8/2/4/0/8240213/ap_multiple_choice.pdf)

Let $g$ be a continuous function on the closed interval $\left[0, 1\right]$. Let
$g\left(0\right)=1$ and $g\left(1\right)=0$. Which of the following is NOT necessarily true?

A. There exists a number $h$ in $\left[0, 1\right]$ such that
$g\left(h\right)\geq g\left(x\right)$ for all $x$ in $\left[0, 1\right]$.

B. For all $a$ and $b$ in $\left[0, 1\right]$, if $a=b$, then
$g\left(a\right)=g\left(b\right)$.

C.There exists a number $h$ in $\left[0, 1\right]$ such that
$g\left(h\right)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}$.

D.There exists a number $h$ in $\left[0, 1\right]$ such that
$g\left(h\right)=\displaystyle\frac{3}{2}$

E. For all $h$ in the open interval $\left(0, 1\right)$,
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow h}g\left(x\right)=g\left(h\right)$.

has the answer as this:

D could be false, consider $g\left(x\right)=1-x$ on $\left[0,1\right]$. A is true by the Extreme Value Theorem, B is true because g is a function, C is true by the Intermediate Value Theorem, and E is true because g is continuous.

---

My question is, isn't B only necessarily true if $f\left(x\right)$ is a one-to-one function?

Edit: maybe I'm confusing myself, but B is necessarily true if it's 1-to-1 but nothing in the question says that. So I think it's not necessarily true.

2nd edit: yes, I get it now. Selection B is saying that if we have the same inputs we should get the same outputs and that's because it's a function.

Comment: The _converse_ of  B would mean that g is one-to-one.  As it stands, B doesn't really say much...  You are correct about choice D: the Intermediate Value Theorem guarantees nothing about function values   $ \ 0 \ > \ g(x) \ $ or $ \ g(x) \  > \ 1 \ $ .

Comment: Try to think of a counterexample: $a,b$ such that $a=b$ but $f(a)\ne f(b)$. This would violate the basic rules of equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost correct! An injective function is defined as as function for which if $f(a) = f(b)$ then $a = b$ or equivalently, if $f(a)\neq f(b)$ then $a\neq b$, that is the implication is the other way around to $B$.

$B$ is in fact always true for all well-defined functions: if we input the same value, we expect the same output.